# Checking if a row in a SQL server table was updated from back end or not

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-update

I have a table called Employee in SQL server. This entries in this table can be updated only through 2 ways and when updated through these 2 ways, those changes are reflected in some other tables also. But someone made some changes from the backend and the corresponding child tables were not updated. Is there any way to find out if a particular row was updated from the back end or not? If yes, when and by whom?

Comment: Maybe try create a log table to store whoever made those changes. Using `Trigger` when any update is performed.

Comment: There were no triggers created in the table and somehow the data in the production environment got updated from the back end. But that updation was not done according to the process flow. May be someone fired the update query from the back end. Now I need to check what all update operations have been done on that table.